# c structure declaration behaviour

Tags: c

I could not come to the reason why i m getting compilation error to this code?Would be great help if someone clarified it.

```
int main()
{
  struct xx
  {
    int x;
    struct yy
   {
    int z;
    struct xx *p;
    };
   struct yy *q;
  };
}
```

Comment: See http://ideone.com/2IzBd for a version of your code that compiles on gcc-4.3.4.

Comment: @Brian L: That would indicate a non-standard compiler extension implemented by GCC in its default configuration. Your ideone code is illegal in both C89/90 and C99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C language you are not allowed to declare `struct` types inside other `struct` types without immediately introducing a data field. I.e. struct declaration and data field declaration should be done in one step (as one declaration). You violated that rule: your `struct yy` definition just sits inside `struct xx` definition for no reason whatsoever.

Either pull the `struct yy` definition outside of `struct xx`, or make sure that `struct yy` definition immediately declares a field of `xx`.

For example, this implements the same intent, but does it correctly

```
  struct xx
  {
    int x;
    struct yy
    {
      int z;
      struct xx *p;
    } *q; // `struct yy` definition is immediately used to declare field `q`
  };
```

However, usually in C language there's no reason to create nested struct definitions. It is usually a better idea to define structs at the same level, without any nesting

```
struct yy
{
  int z;
  struct xx *p;
};

struct xx
{
  int x;
  struct yy *q;
};
```

Why didn't you do it that way from the beginning? What was the point of defining these structs in "nested" fasion?

Comment: but,in the code i gave struct yy is followed by struct yy *q. is that not same as what you gave?What is the difference between those two statements?

Comment: @vindhya: No, it is not "the same". Again, in C you are not allowed to nest struct declarations, unless you do it *as part* of data field declaration. You have to declare the nested struct and the data field *in one step*. If you don't want to do it, don't attempt to nest struct declarations.

Comment: could you please explain whats the difference between data field declaration  and statement struct yy *q?

Comment: @vindhya: There's no difference. `struct yy *q` *is* data field declaration. The problem in your code is the definition of `struct yy` itself. It just sits there by itself. This is nor allowed for nested struct declarations. If you want to declare a struct type by itself - do it in non-nested fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `;` at the statement `struct xx* p`.

```
  struct xx *p;
} *q
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure yy is nested within structure xx. Hence, the elements are of yy are to be accessed through the instance of structure xx, which needs an instance of yy to be known. If the instance is created after defining the
structure the compiler will not know about the instance relative to xx. Hence for nested structure yy you have to
declare member.